# Allow EditText to Scroll while Disabled

Tags: android, xml, scroll, android-edittext

I have an `EditText` set up as follows:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="375dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="top">
        </EditText>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

At a certain point in the program, after text has been typed, the `EditText` becomes disabled by the following code:

```
edittext.setFocusable(false);
edittext.setEnabled(false);
```

The problem is that, once the `EditText` is disabled, I can't scroll up and down to see what I've written. How do I disable more typing, but still allow for review of what's been written?

Comment: For the record, when I tried your code, I already have difficulty in scrolling the `EditText` even before it is disabled. Putting scrollable widget inside `ScrollView` is not a good idea. Is it possible not to fix the height to certain value?

Comment: (1.) The ScrollView does not pose any problems for me; it works exactly as I expect it to. It is actually required for me as it solves a different problem not related to my question here. (2.) The height is fixed that way for another reason not related to this question.

Comment: What about create an invisible textview and when you disable the edittext, you copy the text inside the textview and it appears? Because even if you set textMultiLine to your edittext, there is a bug on lower API, and you will not able to scroll after 2 lines..

Comment: Thanks. That's certainly a doable workaround. If you put it as an answer, and no better suggestions come up, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set `android:inputType="textMultiLine"` on your `EditText`. Even if I already said in comments: *there is a bug on lower API*, but with the fixed height maybe it will work.

However, if this doesn't work, you should create another view as `TextView` with same properties of the `EditText` and also with visibility to `gone`, as follow:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edittext"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="375dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="top" >
        </EditText>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="375dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:visibility="gone" >
        </TextView>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Then, when you handle the `setOnKeyListener` method with `KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN` and `KeyEvent.ACTION_ENTER`, you can copy your text inside the textview and remove your edittext:

```
edittext.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
            String st = edittext.getText().toString();
            textview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            textview.setText(st);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

And you can do a reverse method if you need to rewrite your text.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Setting `android:inputType="textMultiLine"` doesn't seem to do anything, but making an invisible `TextView` then switching it in afterwards does work just fine.