# Android EditText disable edit but allow scrolling

Tags: android, android-edittext

I know that is possible to disable editing `EditText`.

Answers is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29433912/2956344), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13283833/2956344).

But, when i disable EditText it also disabled vertical scroll in this text.

Is it possible to disable only editing, but allow scrolling?

Comment: Try process onTextChanged or some other events instead of setEnable(false)

Comment: @BNK onTextChanged not will be applicable for this problem. onTextChanged called when user type text.

Comment: can i ask you how you disabled the edittext?

Comment: @Sree programmatically. Like that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4297763/disabling-of-edittext-in-android/29433912#29433912

Comment: editText.setEnabled(false); editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);

Comment: Perhaps this will help you ; take a look [here][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22799770/allow-edittext-to-scroll-while-disabled

Comment: I have no PC to test now. I mean you can try some events that prevent the keys entered but not prevent touch :-)

Comment: Hi! Has your issue been solved yet? And how? :)

Comment: @BNK, no one help me, so i just put `EditText` into `RelativeLayout` and put `TextView` above him.

Comment: I have tested my answer before posting here, have you tried? I think you can create a new project with only an editText such as `<EditText android:id="@+id/editText" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/textView" android:scrollbars="vertical" android:text="111111111111111112222222222222444444444444444222222222"/>` then test my code

Comment: @ywwynm answer can be another working way, you can look at the comments between me and him :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
    editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
    editText.clearFocus();
```

Comment: This is the best solution. Clean and elegant as you can toggle back and forth without losing events. Thanks!!!

Comment: This has the problem that it is still possible to copy and paste text into the field. To fix this set: editText.isLongClickable = false

Comment: Good solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Use this porperties in your EdittText:

```
android:enabled="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
```

Your EditText will be enable, but not focusable for edit. Then, you will able to scroll (in vertical on this case) and will not able to edit.

Answer (score 2):

I've found that just disabling the key listener, focusable and cursor seems to work:

```
editText.setKeyListener( null );
editText.setFocusable( false );
editText.setCursorVisible(false);
```

As long as you keep the edit text enabled you seem to be able to scroll the text still.

Comment: If I disable the EditText widget this way how do I enable it back? What should I pass to setKeyListener?

Answer (score 1):

`editText.setKeyListener(null)` should help you.

Comment: Your answer does not work in my phone :), have you checked?

Comment: @BNK Yes, I use it to disable edit in `EditText` and it can still scroll.

Comment: How did you declare editText inside layout file? Mine is `<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:text="111111111111111112222222222222444444444444444222222222"/>`

Comment: @BNK I don't have scrollbars="vertical".

Comment: I just remove scrollbars, setOnKeyListener(null) still does not work for my phone (Android 4.1.2)

Comment: Ok, setKeyListenter works with `<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="111111111111111112222222222222444444444444444222222222"/>`

Comment: @BNK Why are you using `singleLine="true"`? It seems that with this property you are not likely to scroll since the `EditText` has only one line of content.

Comment: In my app, if not set singleLine true, the editText expands to multiple lines, and no scroll :), can you show your layout of editText?

Comment: Use `editText.setInputType(0);` no need to set `android:singleLine="true"`

Answer (score 1):

If you wrap your `EditText` in a `ScrollView` then you should be able to preserve the scroll behavior.

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText ... />

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use these two attributes to your editext it will make your editext only scrollable not editable 
                    android:inputType="none"
                    android:textIsSelectable="true"
Below is the example

```
               <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="start"
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
                android:inputType="none"
                android:textIsSelectable="true"
                android:textStyle="normal"
                android:id="@+id/toeditext"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                />
```